# Why are my symbolic x coordinate labels printed twice in a tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I'm trying to plot a bar graph, using `symbolic x coordinate`s.

For some reason, the name of some symbolic coordinates appears under the x axis more than once.

[image: graph]

If I increase the width (e.g. 12cm) the number of duplicates increases. If I decrease the `width` (e.g. 6cm), the duplicates go away. However simply reducing the width isn't a satisfactory solution. I need to be able to have a large `width`, because I want to use some long symbolic coordinate names.

Here's my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [width=8cm,
              symbolic x coords={egg,corn,spoon}]
\addplot  plot coordinates{
             (egg,2)
             (corn,6) 
             (spoon,7)
          };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add `xtick=data` so that `xtick`s are taken from data.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [width=8cm,
              symbolic x coords={egg,corn,spoon},xtick=data]
\addplot  plot coordinates{
             (egg,2)
             (corn,6)
             (spoon,7)
          };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]